# Polymorphism - construct an object of the same type

Tags: java, polymorphism

Let's consider this example:

```
class InheritedType extends Type {

    public Type simplify() {
        Type newLeft = left.simplify();
        Type newRight = right.simplify();
        Type newExpr = new InheritedType(newLeft, newRight);
        return newExpr.simplify();
    }
}
```

Now I'd create another inherited type

```
class InheritedType2 extends Type {

    public Type simplify() {
        Type newLeft = left.simplify();
        Type newRight = right.simplify();
        Type newExpr = new InheritedType2(newLeft, newRight);
        return newExpr.simplify();
    }
}
```

This method is just the same, only the constructor name differs. Is there any way to avoid code duplication? The following code doesn't work

```
class Type {

    public Type simplify() {
        Type newLeft = left.simplify();
        Type newRight = right.simplify();
        Type newExpr = new this(newLeft, newRight);
        return newExpr.simplify();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not really make sense. Every call to `simplify` ends with a recursive call to `simplify`. Your methods refer to fields that are not declared, so it's not clear where you intend them to be declared. You should post a minimal *correct* example if you want useful advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way around this problem is to introduce a common superclass for `InheritedType` and `InheritedType2`. This is because, clearly, those two types share logic, mainly: they operate both on left and right operands. So let us create a `LeftRightType` (for lack of a better name):

```
abstract class LeftRightType extends Type {

    private Type left, right;

    public LeftRightType(Type left, Type right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public Type simplify() {
        return newInstance(left.simplify(), right.simplify()).simplify();
    }

    public abstract Type newInstance(Type left, Type right);

}
```

It holds the logic you are currently duplicating and delegate the creation of the concrete instance into a `newInstance` abstract method that implementors will override. Then you can simply have

```
class InheritedType extends LeftRightType {
    public InheritedType(Type left, Type right) {
        super(left, right);
    }
    @Override
    public Type newInstance(Type left, Type right) {
        return new InheritedType(left, right);
    }
}

class InheritedType2 extends LeftRightType {
    public InheritedType2(Type left, Type right) {
        super(left, right);
    }
    @Override
    public Type newInstance(Type left, Type right) {
        return new InheritedType2(left, right);
    }
}
```

---

Note that if you're using Java 8, you can condense that a lot by giving the concrete class to return directly in the constructor. You don't even need an abstract method anymore.

```
abstract class LeftRightType extends Type {

    private Type left, right;
    private BinaryOperator<Type> typeSupplier;

    public LeftRightType(Type left, Type right, BinaryOperator<Type> typeSupplier) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.typeSupplier = typeSupplier;
    }

    public Type simplify() {
        return typeSupplier.apply(left.simplify(), right.simplify()).simplify();
    }
}
```

and then have

```
class InheritedType extends LeftRightType {
    public InheritedType(Type left, Type right) {
        super(left, right, InheritedType::new);
    }
}

class InheritedType2 extends LeftRightType {
    public InheritedType2(Type left, Type right) {
        super(left, right, InheritedType2::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you "curiously recurring template pattern" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern:

```
abstract class Type<This extends Type<This>> {
  protected abstract This newInstance(Type<?> newLeft, Type<?> newRight);

    public This simplify() {
        Type<?> newLeft = left.simplify();
        Type<?> newRight = right.simplify();
        This newExpr = newInstance(newLeft, newRight);
        return newExpr.simplify();
    }
}

class InheritedType extends Type<InheritedType> {
    protected InheritedType newInstance(Type<?> left, Type<?> right) {
        new InheritedType(left, right);
    }
}

class InheritedType2 extends Type<InheritedType2> {
    protected InheritedType2 newInstance(Type<?> left, Type<?> right) {
        new InheritedType2(left, right);
    }
}
```